# can we return a null from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can we return  null value from stored procedure. i dont want to use collase or isnull. I want to capture NULL at the frontend. Is it possible ?

**Edit:**

> I am using `Sql Server 2005`

eg. where i want to use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Authentication].[spOnlineTest_CheckLogin]

  @UserName  NVARCHAR(50)
AS
 BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
                    COMMIT TRAN
     RETURN NULL
        END TRY
```

**Error** 
The 'spOnlineTest_CheckLogin' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: @Justin: Q is tagged T-SQL. It's SQL Server.

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari, Sybase uses T-SQL as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the return type of a stored procedure is `INT` and it cannot be null.

Comment: Input parameters to Stored Procedures can be INT and still be assigned NULL so why not RETURN parameters?

Comment: @Chris: that's how the language is designed. I suspect for the its intended use case as a failure/success status, not being null makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

use an output parameter, example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
  @UserName  NVARCHAR(50), @Status int output
AS
 BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN
                    COMMIT TRAN
     set @Status = null
        END TRY
        begin catch
        end catch
        go
```

then call it like this

```
  declare @s int 
  set @s =5
  exec Test'bla',@s output
  select @s --will be null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of a proc like follows. Let me first set the context. We might have a table `Table1(id int, name varchar(2), Address varchar(2))` and want to get the id and if not found, it will be null. So we might write a proc like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetId
  @Name  VARCHAR(50), @Status int output
AS
 BEGIN TRY
     set @Status = null
     select @Status = id from Table1 where name=@name
```

This will work for you.